# Set Hybrid Sleep time in Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: linux-mint, hybrid-sleep

In Linux Mint 18.3 there is "Enable Hybrid Sleep" (to replace Suspend) option in power management settings.
How can I set the time after which the system "hibernates" itself to disk?

Answer (score 2):

Hit the menu and type in 'Power' to call up Power Management (System Settings).

'Suspend when iactive for...' select 5 minutes up to 3 hours.
Suspend means 'sleep'. If you enabled 'hybrid sleep' then this is backed up by saving RAM to disk. Works well if you have an SSD.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. I couldn't find the hybrid sleep option though, using Mint 18.3 MATE